# Using flash to trigger a file upload dialog

Tags: flash, file-upload

Does anyone know of a simple transparent flash file that I can place ontop of a hyperlink, whereby clicking this region brings up a file selection dialog?

From what I can tell, gmail uses a transparent flash on top of the file upload link which in turn triggers a JS function to perform the upload.

Something like this would be handy and I really don't want to learn flash for a small task such as this :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ready-made flash files availible on the web (http://swfupload.org/ et al).